# How can I solve this 3D regular grid interpolation problem

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, h5py, pytables

I am a new python user. I have a h5 file, which is a snapshot of gravitational potential at a fixed redshift. I have read the h5 file in python and now I want to write a code which will give the value of the gravitational potential for given values of (x, y, z) by using trilinear interpolation. Can anyone of you please help me to do that? For your kind consideration, the code is given below:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import h5py

In [3]: from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

In [4]: f = h5py.File('my.h5', 'r')

In [5]: list(f.keys())
Out[5]: [u'data']

In [6]: data = f[u'data']

In [7]: data.shape
Out[7]: (64, 64, 64)

In [8]: data.dtype
Out[8]: dtype(('<f8', (3,)))

In [9]: data[0:63, 0:63, 0:63]
Out[9]: 
array([[[[ 7.44284016e-09, -3.69665900e-09,  8.75937447e-10],
         [ 8.00073078e-09, -2.62747161e-09,  9.82415717e-11],
         [ 7.81088465e-09, -2.03862452e-09, -4.00492778e-10],
         ...,
         [ 4.98376989e-09, -3.97621746e-09,  2.25554383e-09],
         [ 5.54899844e-09, -4.09876187e-09,  2.01146743e-09],
         [ 6.03652599e-09, -4.03159468e-09,  1.47328647e-09]],..............................
```

Suppose, I want to find the value of potential at point (4.98376989e-09, -3.97621746e-09,  2.25554383e-09) by using #RegularGridInterpolator function. How can I do that?

Comment: `RegularGridInterpolator()` has 2 primary inputs: 1) a tuple of points to define the grid, and 2) an array of values at each grid. If I understand your example `data` is an array of grid points. You need to slice it into 3 arrays (x,y,z) and reference as a tuple. Where is the array of values defined? The scipy docs have a simple example that clarify the use of each variable.

Comment: Which part of the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html) do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I don't understand this part of the docs:                >>> from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
>>> def f(x,y,z):
...     return 2 * x**3 + 3 * y**2 - z
>>> x = np.linspace(1, 4, 11)
>>> y = np.linspace(4, 7, 22)
>>> z = np.linspace(7, 9, 33)
>>> data = f(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True)). Because already I have a dataset so, is it necessary to define (x, y, z) here? How can I make slice of my dataset? Can you please suggest me?

Comment: The statements `x/y/z= np.linspace( )` populate 3 arrays defining the grid. These are locations in space (e.g. x,y,z together define the coordinates). The `data=f( )` creates a set of values at the associated x/y/z locations. If I understand your question, the dataset you extract as `data` from the HDF5 file are your `values` (same as the example). Correct? If so, where are the x/y/z values that define the locations for these values? That's the part you need.

Comment: @Photon-Are you still working on this problem? Did my answer make sense? I think you need to review all the data sets to find the one(s) with the mesh definition.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response. Thanks a lot, that particular problem has solved and obviously your response helped me a lot. Thanks again. Can you  please add one thing, how can I see the plot to make sure only that my interpolation works well?

Comment: Plotting the data is a whole different topic. :-) Do you have a way to plot your input data (that form the interpolation grid)? If so, I would export your interpolated data, and use the same method to plot and compare them. You can also create some points close to some of your interpolation grid points, and see if the interpolated values are close the data values.

Comment: Hi, I can't give my code in comment section. I have given it in the answer section. Can you please have a look at that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting (and tricky) enough question that I decided it deserved an answer to demonstrate the scipy interpolate example using data from an HDF5 file. There are 2 code sections below.

1. The first populates a HDF5 file with the mesh definition and
   mesh_data used in the interpolation.
2. The second opens the HDF5 file from Step 1 and reads the `x,y,z,
   mesh_data` datasets as Numpy arrays used in the example.

**Run this code to create the HDF5 file:**

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

def f(x,y,z):
   return 2 * x**3 + 3 * y**2 - z

x = np.linspace(1, 4, 11)
y = np.linspace(4, 7, 22)
z = np.linspace(7, 9, 33)
mesh_data = f(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True))

h5file = h5py.File('interpolate_test.h5', 'w')
h5file.create_dataset('/x', data=x)
h5file.create_dataset('/y', data=y)
h5file.create_dataset('/z', data=z)
h5file.create_dataset('/mesh_data', data=mesh_data)

h5file.close()
```

**Then, run this code to read the HDF5 file with h5py and do the interpolation:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import h5py

h5file = h5py.File('interpolate_test.h5')

x = h5file['x'][:]
y = h5file['y'][:]
z = h5file['z'][:]
mesh_data = h5file['mesh_data'][:,:,:]

my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), mesh_data)

pts = np.array([[2.1, 6.2, 8.3], [3.3, 5.2, 7.1]])
print (my_interpolating_function(pts))
```

Resulting output should look like this (which is identical to the scipy example):

```
[125.80469388 146.30069388]
```

For those that use the Pytables API to read HDF5 data, here is an alternative method for Step 2 above. The process to read the data is similar, only the calls are different.

**Run this code to read the HDF5 file with Pytables and do the interpolation:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import tables

h5file = tables.open_file('interpolate_test.h5')

x = h5file.root.x.read()
y = h5file.root.y.read()
z = h5file.root.z.read()
mesh_data = h5file.root.mesh_data.read()

my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), mesh_data)

pts = np.array([[2.1, 6.2, 8.3], [3.3, 5.2, 7.1]])
print (my_interpolating_function(pts))
```

Resulting output should be identical to above (and to the scipy example):

```
[125.80469388 146.30069388]
```

Comment: It occurred to me that some may want to use Pytables to read the HDF5 data. See below for Step 2 done with Pytables.

Comment: Is it possible to get the interpolated result for the whole dataset stored in the hdf file? Or, is it possible to update the pts automatically without mentioning? @kcw78

Comment: My example has 4 datasets in the h5 file to define the interpolation mesh coordinates (the `x,y,z` datasets) and the data values at those points (the `mesh_data` dataset). If you have another dataset of X/Y/X points for interpolation, follow the last 2 steps in the code above. Load your coordinates into a np.array (similar to `pts` above) and call `my_interpolating_function(pts)` with a return value. The returned array contains your interpolated results. To save, write the data to the h5 file with `create_dataset` as shown in the **Create the HDF5 file** step above.