# How to define a hdf5 file as a function of some dependent variables?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, hdf5, h5py

I need your kind suggestion. I have a hdf5 file and I can able to read the file in python. The h5 file contains a large number of data and these are the values of potential (depends on position (x, y, z) ). I am also able to interpolate my 3D regular grid data by using RegularGridInterpolator. Now, my question is: how I can define my h5 file data as a function of x, y, z so that it can able to update my a_1 (x,y,z) , a_2(x,y,z)... values in my code. Here is the link of my h5 file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OFIg7pjfpfjq3Vnvqaj2uyCFjiTwZ9QK

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import gradient
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

f = h5py.File('k.h5', 'r') 
list(f.keys())
dset = f[u'data']
dset.shap
dset.value.shape
dset[0:64, 0:64, 0:64]
x = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
y = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
z = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)

my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), dset.value)
pts = np.array([100, 5, -10])  
my_interpolating_function(pts)

# Apply gradient function
gradx, grady, gradz = np.gradient(dset.value)
gradx.shape

# To find the gradient at any point
gradx_interpol = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), gradx)
grady_interpol = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), grady)
gradz_interpol = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), gradz)


def get_val_and_grads(pts):
    v1, x1, y1, z1 = my_interpolating_function(pts), gradx_interpol(
        pts), grady_interpol(pts), gradz_interpol(pts)
    return v1, x1, y1, z1


##getting_interpolated_values

k1 = my_interpolating_function(pts)
k_dx = gradx_interpol(pts)
k_dy = grady_interpol(pts)
k_dz = gradz_interpol(pts)

def a_1(x,y,z):

    return  -(adot/a**2)*k1

def a_2(x,y,z):

    return (1/a)*k_dx
```

Comment: This is more about scipy and interpolation than HDF5. Take a look at this topic. It has some guidance for `RegularGridInterpolator` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758209)

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks for your kind suggestion with link. I have checked the link and understand that it's helpful for reading and interpolating any hdf5 file. But my concern is that my h5 file contains the values of potential which is depends on position (x, y, z). So, I have to define my interpolating function in such a way so that my potential values depend on x, y, z and update the values of a_1 and a_2 as they are depends on x, y, z. Can you please help me how I can define my interpolating function so that it's depend on x, y, z.

Comment: I will try to help (can't access your file). First, the link is _helpful for reading and interpolating_ **any data on a 3d Mesh**. Data source doesn't matter. Have you done the scipy example without a h5 file? I would expect to find 4 datasets in your sample file: 1 each for the X, Y and Z coordinates to define the grid, and 1 for the potential values at all X/Y/Z values above. In your code, you define the X/Y/Z values with linspace (not retrieved from the H5 file). Next you need a return variable when you call `my_interpolating_function(pts)` if you want to use it later.

Comment: @kcw78 Thanks for your kind feedback. I am sorry as my previous link doesn't work. You can get the file from here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14lrChd9nn8M3HqH3GQrCT7OXBxVSYuD8 . Can you please help me again how can I define 4 data set from my sample file? Expecting your kind suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help. Your question has more to do with scipy `RegularGridInterpolator()` than with HDF5. HDF5 is just a data source. I suggest you work thru the scipy example before using HDF5. It shows how the grid coordinates and values are defined and used by the interpolation function.

I looked at your HDF5 file (`k.h5`). It only has one dataset with the potential values at the mesh points. It does not have coordinates at the mesh points (the x,y,z values). You defined the x,y,z coordinates with these lines in your code:

```
x = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
y = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
z = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
```

The coordinates and values are usually stored together. The way you are doing it, you could associate ANY x,y,z coordinates to these mesh values. Is that your intent?

I reworked the first part of your code to interpolate a few values. See below. I am not familiar with `np.gradient()`, so can't help with that part.
The first call to `RegularGridInterpolator()` (and returned value) is done with the x,y,z value you provided above.
The second call to `RegularGridInterpolator()` (and returned values) is done for the corner coordinates for your dataset (the first/last values). It confirms the interpolator returns the "right answer".

**Updated code to interpolate values:**

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import gradient
import h5py
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

f = h5py.File('k.h5', 'r') 
list(f.keys())
dset = f[u'data'][:,:,:]
print ('dset.shape=', dset.shape)
print ('dset.first/last=', dset[0,0,0], dset[-1,-1,-1])

x = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
y = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
z = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)

my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), dset)

pts = np.array([100, 5, -10])
print ('pts=', pts)
vals_at_pts = my_interpolating_function(pts)
print ('vals_at_pts=', vals_at_pts)

pts = np.array([[-160, -160, -160], [160, 160, 160]])
print ('pts=', pts)
vals_at_pts = my_interpolating_function(pts)
print ('vals_at_pts=', vals_at_pts)
```

**Output:**

```
dset.shape= (64, 64, 64)
dset.first/last= -2.386316671021661e-05 -2.966368162003158e-05
pts= [100   5 -10]
vals_at_pts= [-3.0528203e-07]
pts= [[-160 -160 -160]  [ 160  160  160]]
vals_at_pts= [-2.38631667e-05 -2.96636816e-05]
```